# Reportlab's RGBA Color tutorial code not working (the RGB part doesn't affect the result)

Tags: colors, alpha, reportlab

I'm trying to use reportlab's Color class in order to add some transparency to my fill colors, and it's not working. I'm following the example from reportlab's website itself ([here](https://www.reportlab.com/snippets/9/)) and the only thing that makes changes to the result is the alpha value. The rgb values don't seem to affect the color I print (i.e. it's always a translucent shade of white)

For example:

```
color1 = Color(200, 100, 100, 0.5)
c = Canvas(filename,pagesize=(400,200))

c.setFillColor(black)
c.rect(0, 0, 100, 100, fill=1)
c.setFillColor(color1)
c.rect(0, 0, 50, 50, fill=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the tutorial on reportlab's website is wrong. RGB values should be in the 0~1 range instead of the usual 0~256, which was what the tutorial used. Changing this fixed it.